# Missing grey background around div and orange background on buttons

Tags: html, css

I'd like my entire div to have the background color #e2e3e4 go all the way around. Currently it only covers the top half and then stops.

Also, on my "Webinar" links, it supposed to have a grey bar with dark text and then the hover state changes to an orange bar with white text. Currently you just see "Webinar" with no change on hover. Please help.

Here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/huskydawgs/0zfwf2dk/12/

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="resources">
<div class="column-resources">
    <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple"><img alt="Apples" height="73" src="http://www.hapadesign.com/images/apples.jpg" width="193" /></a>
    <h4 class="bar">
        <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple">WEBINAR</a></h4>
</div>
</div>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
.resources {
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: #e2e3e4;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.column-resources {
    width: 193px;
    float: left;
    margin: 15px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}

.column-resources img {
border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
}

.column-resources a {
color: #232323;

h4 {
font-family: Georgia,Helvetica,Arial;
font-size: 1.1em;
font-weight: normal;
margin: 1em 0 .6em 0;
}

h4.bar a {
font-family: Georgia;
font-size: 11px !important;
color: #232323 !important;
background-color: #b7b7b7;
padding-top: 4px;
padding-bottom: 4px;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
display: block;
}

h4.bar a:hover {
background-color: #f66511;
color: #fff !important;
}
```

Comment: I noticed my images are a couple pixels longer than the "Webinar" bar. How do I get the "Webinar" bar to be equal width to the images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add:

```
.resources {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

And this one missing close tag `}`

```
.column-resources a {
color: #232323;
```

Fix that, it'll be all good.

**Edit:** to fix image width, try adding this:

```
.column-resources img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using floats inside the resources div you have to add this:

```
.resources:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

And for your links: Just add a missing closing bracket here:

```
.column-resources a {
    color: #232323;}
```